# How to convert a list of lists into a singular set

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

While trying to find the intersection of sets within the `setOfsets` gives the error mentioned below.

Example setA = [['1','2'], ['2,3'], '['2','4']]

I know that it can't have an intersection of "Lists" datatype, and I tried converting it into a set, but it didn't work

```
def multiple_set_intersection(*sets):
    """Return multiple set intersection."""
    try:
        return set.intersection(*sets)
    except TypeError: # this is Python < 2.6 or no arguments
        pass

    try: a_set= sets[0]
    except IndexError: # no arguments
        return set() # return empty set

    return reduce(a_set.intersection, sets[1:])

multiple_set_intersection(*setOfSets)
```

Expected result : Intersection of all the sets present inside of `setOfSets` I.e `intersection = 2`

Actual result :

```
return reduce(a_set.intersection, sets[1:])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'intersection'
```

Comment: Please share the lists so this is easier to answer

Comment: `setA` and the elements in it are lists not sets

Comment: So and what is the expented output?

Comment: Please share full list of `setOfSets`

Comment: a list of lists is an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your lists to set first. Because `set.intersection` is a method for `set` not for `list`.

- Assuming your `setOfSets` contain list of lists. See sample in code. What you can do is to map each list to set while calling `set.interseciton`.

```
def multiple_set_intersection(*sets):
    """Return multiple set intersection."""
    try:
        return set.intersection(*map(set,sets))
    except TypeError: # this is Python < 2.6 or no arguments
        pass

    try: a_set= map(set,sets[0])
    except IndexError: # no arguments
        return set() # return empty set

    return set.intersection(*map(set,l))

setOfSets = [['1','2'], ['2','3'], ['2','4']]
print(multiple_set_intersection(*setOfSets))
```

**PS: If your input is like specified in above code then this will work.**

Comment: I just removed the entire function and wrote a simple for loop

Comment: `for z in range(0, num):
    intersectionOfall= set(setOfSets[z]).intersection(*setOfSets)
`

Comment: @SakshatShinde Check this updated solution it works for your given input. I hope this is something you are trying to do.

Comment: Yup, was pretty simple

Comment: Thank you! Hope It will help others in case someone would be trying to implement it differently